# Does angular trigger change detection when setting a variable to the same value

Tags: angular

I was wondering if, doing so

```html
<nav [class.haveScrolled]="haveScrolled"></nav>
```

```js
haveScrolled = false

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
checkOffsetTop() {
  this.haveScrolled = window.pageYOffset !== 0
}
```

Will force a rerendering of the element even if I do set the same value to the `haveScrolled` variable over and over again

Comment: I would say it does trigger re-render but because of the hostlistener [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-33l9hp?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I don't think so, putting a method directly into the html will trigger, on any event, this method. If you remove the hostListener then you'll see that this is still be triggered

Comment: Well yes, other events will trigger change detection unless you override change detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the answer would be: it depends on the browser's rendering engine optimizations. For example, using Chrome (Version 97.0.4692.71), the element is repainted only when the `haveScrolled` class has been added to or removed from the DOM. Here is a showcase using Chrome's Rendering tools. Whatever flashes in green represents the occurrence of a new paint event:

[image]

I performed the test on [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ztrqgj?file=src/app/app.component.html).

This particular use-case demonstrates what browsers that use the Blink rendering engine would do. I would guess that, for example, Firefox might handle the painting cases differently.

Keep in mind that the StackBlitz example I have provided has a very simple component structure and in no way reflects how an actual real-world app would behave. Usually, the more complex the component structure/interaction is, the more painting events would occur. I encourage you to use your browser's dev tools to monitor the overall performance of the app.

Comment: Thx for this explanation. It's true I should have though at giving a look ath the chrome rendering paint flashing tool and I will. But isn't the reredering depending on how angular works ?

Comment: Generally, what Angular (as any other JS framework) does is manipulate the DOM in some way. Angular "decides" on what to reach the actual DOM, depending on its own rendering logic and yes, its lifecycle events do trigger the browser to rerender stuff, if needed. In the case you have laid out, Angular performs change detection when the user is scrolling and thus, it's constantly checking whether `window.pageYOffset !== 0` is true. But even if the expression is constantly evaluated as truthy as you scroll, the browser does not constantly repaint the element.

Comment: So the response yet is, no, when reassigning the same value to a variable, angular do perform change detection, but do not rerender that specific html element. Thx a lot for your explanation <3

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **YES**, even if it's not in a HostListener.

try to play with this and you will see what happens ;)

```js
private _haveScrolled = false;
set haveScrolled(haveScrolled: boolean) {
  console.log('set hasScrolled');
  this._haveScrolled = haveScrolled;
}
get haveScrolled(): boolean {
  console.log('get hasScrolled');
  return this._haveScrolled;
}
```

in ngOnInit:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  this.haveScrolled = false;
}, 1000);
```

and

```js
// see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence
ngDoCheck() {
  console.log('do check ')
}
```

you will alway see "do check" even without a getter/setter

Comment: Thx, but this isn't a response to the question on the if yes or no this is forcing a rerendering the DOM

Comment: it's not forcing anything. If you see the console.log, then changedetection gets triggered.
I can't answer you question directly because it also depends on other factors such as changeDetection strategy and so on. Just test it and you have you answer.

Comment: But, I mean, for sure you'll have the log being displayed . I mean, I can add the log into my own function and it would do the same, or or wouldn't it ? I'm not sur I understand you here,  But the strategy is `Default` because it wouldn't work otherwise. What I do not understand is, when I do set a variable with the same value, did this value change or not ?

Comment: yes. I edited the original answer

Comment: Well, the accepted answer stipule something else, and after having testing it, it does look like she's right. Can you remove your answer since it's wrong ? I would be glad not having to downvote it

Comment: thats strange, i tested it in my code and I always see the "do check" log.
Anyway it's not a good idea to delete an answer on stackoverflow even if you think it's wrong. People can learn from other's mistakes. Feel free to downvote

Comment: Yes you'll have the log, and therefore you didn't understand my question. The question wasn't about the check, but the DOM did get rerendered. So you're answer is, in my opinion, not helping a lot in this discussion